# Unable to upload multiple python dataframes to s3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I am trying to upload google play console reports to s3 using boto3. The code below works well when i try to print dataframes in loop, which means i am successfully getting the files i need.

```
from io import StringIO # python3; python2: BytesIO
import boto3
import os
from google.cloud import storage
import pandas as pd
import io

jsonfile = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'private_key.json')

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]= jsonfile


# getting all file names from bucket
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket_name = 'pubsite_prod_rev_1223445566778899'
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
#blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
allblobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name)

# filtering out the files i need. for example: abc/123/game1/201801_channel.csv,abc/123/game1/202110_channel.csv
for blobfile in allblobs:
    if "abc/123" in blobfile.name:
        if "game1" in blobfile.name:
            if "channel.csv" in blobfile.name:
             #print(blobfile.name) # successfully getting all file names
             source_blob_name = blobfile.name
             blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
             data = blob.download_as_string()
             df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(data),encoding='utf-16')

             print(df) # successfully printing dataframes for all of the files

            #upload files to s3
             bucket = 'the-knights-iaps-raw' # already created on S3
             csv_buffer = StringIO()
             df.to_csv(csv_buffer)
             s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id='JE4WNFJCN24JNJN13FC',aws_secret_access_key = 'jdsafjlhsafj34j32n4tj23nZ')

             fileNamefors3 = source_blob_name.split("/", 2)
             s3_resource.Object(bucket, "Acquisition/Buyers7d/StickmanAdventureGame/Channel/"+fileNamefors3[2]).put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
```

But uploading all these dataframes to s3 is causing an error:

> File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\Gamexis_gpc\cvcv.py", line 28,
> in 
> blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'blob'

I am not python pro but that would be great if someone can help.

Comment: You are re-using `bucket`. Initially it's a bucket object, then you change it to a string via `bucket = 'the-knights-iaps-raw'`. Fix the latter usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you're creating the bucket:

```
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
```

.. but then later on inside the for loop you overwrite that variable:

```
bucket = 'the-knights-iaps-raw'
```

Use a different variable name for the string.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Actually i was using same variable name for google storage bucket and aws s3 bucket.